# Strings, references, and Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, .net, string, garbage-collection

Imagine you have an object that has several properties.  One of these properties is a string:

```
private class MyObject
{
    public string PropertyOne {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

I now create a new object, based on the contents on `MyObject`:

```
private class MySecondObject
{
    public string PropertyOneCopy {get; set;}

    public MySecondObject(MyObject myObject)
    {
        this.PropertyOneCopy = myObject.PropertyOne;
        ....
    }
}
```

In the calling scenario we have:

```
private class Scenario
{
    private MySecondObject _mySecondObject;

    public void Go()
    {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.PropertyOne = "Hello, World!";

        _mySecondObject = new MySecondObject(myObject);
    }
}
```

The original instance of MyObject now falls out of scope.  _mySecondObject is long -living.

The question I have is.... will the original MyObject ever be garbage collected?  Would it be if I used `this.PropertyOneCopy = String.Copy(myObject.PropertyOne);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object that used to be in `myObject` will be garbage collected normally, because there is no outstanding reference to it.

There is still a reference to the `string` object that used to be the value of the `PropertyOne` property of `myObject`, but that will only prevent the *string* from being reclaimed, not the whole `MyObject` instance.

`String.Copy` does nothing special, it's simply there to serve as a constructor that accepts a `string` instance and creates a duplicate object (`System.String` has no such constructor).

Answer (score 3):

It will be garbage collected for sure. Even if you don't use String.Copy.

The string has no references to any other objects... instead, what you have is an object tha has a reference to a string... what happens to that string has nothing to do with objects that have reference to that same string.

*Example:*

If you have objects A, B, and C, all of them have a string property assigned like this:

```
string s = "str";
A.Str = s;
B.Str = A.Str;
C.Str = B.Str;
```

is the same as doing:

```
string s = "str";
A.Str = s;
B.Str = s;
C.Str = s;
```

When A is no longer used, it can die, without influencing the other objects, even if they share the same string.

Answer (score 1):

> will the original MyObject ever be garbage collected?

Yes, it only has *outgoing* references here. Nothing to keep it from the GC.

The `"Hello, World!"` string is co-owned and will stay alive as long as 1 of the objects is alive.

Using the GC is easier than you seem to think, you almost never have to 'help'.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET garbage collecter will reclaim memory used by objects that are no longer reachable by any references. The reference to `MyObject` disappears when `Go` exits making the instance of `MyObject` eligble for garbage collection. That `MyObject` references a string that also has a reference stored in `MySecondObject` does not make any difference.

Comment: `MySecondObject` doesn't hold the reference, it only uses it for the duration of the constructor.

Comment: Where do you see `MySecondObject` storing a reference to a `MyObject`? It only stores a string.

Answer (score 0):

MySecondObject has a reference to the string in MyObject, not to the MyObject-object itself, so myObject will be released to the GC as soon as you exit the Go-function, so no need to worry.

If you instead would have implementeded in this way myObject would have not been released till MySecondObject is released:

```
private class MySecondObject {

    private MyObject myObject;

    public string PropertyOneCopy {
        get{
            return myObject.PropertyOne;
        }
    }

    public MySecondObject(MyObject myObject)     {
        myObject = myObject.PropertyOne;
        ....
    }
}
```